# Al parecer jtable (jquery) ya esta quedando en el pasado

Tags: jtable

Que alternativa recomendarían que tenga la mismas funciones asíncronas de jtable?

Comment: Esta pregunta está basada en opiniones, será cerrada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se porque dices que esta quedando en el pasado, yo la veo bastante en uso todavía, pero si quieres explorar otras alternativas, [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) la he usado en algún proyecto y me parece una buena alternativa.